# Getting different results for params value in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular-router

I've been getting my hands on the new Angular version before this I had worked on below 2 versions. So, this is kind of new for me. I was working on a small project where I was working with routing and getting a value from params and passing it to a function to get results from an API. I got a strange outcome to this one.

I've two examples here:

First example

```
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private movieService: MovieService) { }
this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
  const id = params['id']; //this works fine
});
```

second example

```
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private movieService: MovieService) { }
this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
  const id = params.id;//this doesn't gives me undefined
});
```

If I'm not wrong aren't both methods for accessing object keys correct? I've not noticed such behaviour before. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do mention about your router variable. I think it is activatedRoute.
Anyways, I have tried both ways of extracting the params and both works.
Alternatively you could use [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot) for extracting the params.

Here is the code using activated route snapshot

```
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

You can find more about activated route [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

Comment: I've made the edits to now let everyone know it's activatedRoute. So, you say both worked for you? No undefined value?

Comment: Strange! Just to be sure we talking about params.id right? In the mean time I'll try again with a simple static route.

Comment: This is the strangest thing happened to me. Now it's working fine. I just don't understand what to say.